# Order of actions when synchronizing a list

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I want to understand how Java exactly works when synchronizing a list.
Let us suppose I have this code:

```
List list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());

synchronized(list) {
      Iterator i = list.iterator();
      while (i.hasNext())
          foo(i.next());
}
```

and that a thread (thread 1) is executing it.

Another thread (thread 2) makes:

```
list.add(....)
```

while the previous code is being executed in the thread 1.

Will thread 2 wait until thread 1 finishes that code? Synchronzing is like "waiting for the other one to finish"?

Or, for example, if 3 threads reach some code wrapped by `synchronized(list) {}`, will they start it only by order but never simultaneously?

Comment: If another thread t2 update the list then it will throw exception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will thread 2 wait until thread 1 finishes that code?, ie, syncronzying is like "waiting for the other one to finish"?

**Yes** If some thread acquired the lock, then no other thread can acquire the same lock until the initial thread releases it.

> Or, for example, if 3 threads reach some code wrapped by synchronized(list) {}, will they start it only by order but never simultaneously?

**Yes, in order**, but the order is not specified. From your point of view it could be any of the 3 threads that acquire it first.

**P.S.** Mutex acquire (synchronised) does not have any *fairness*. Which Thread and when it acquires the lock is not specified. *For example:* if you have Thread A that holds a lock and there are other 3 threads waiting for the same lock, and Thread A after some time releases the lock; then **any** of the 4 Threads (including Thread A) can take that lock

Comment: Thank you Eugene.
I just do not understand what "mutex" is.

Comment: @Tatanan 'Mutex' stands for [Mutual Exclusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutex).

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the source code behind `Collections.synchronizedList` you'll see it creates an instance of `Collections.SynchronizedList`, which locks using an internal `mutex` that is set to `this` when no other value is passed.

Your code locks on the `list` instance itself, so will work when using `Collections.synchronizedList(List)` but the use of `List.iterator` must my synchronized manually to avoid `ConcurrentModificationException`s.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Synchronization is not at method level/code level. It is at object level.
> 2. If you are synchronizing on an object, any thread which access the object must first get a lock on the object's monitor.
> 3. If the thread1 has the lock on the monitor, then any other threads trying to access that object will have to wait until thread1 releases the lock.

Comment: In general terms, the object can still be accessed without obtaining the monitor

Answer (score 1):

In your example, thread 2 will wait, as thread 1 has acquired the lock on the synchronized List.

Generally speaking, code wrapped in a synchronized block is executed completely before the "next" synchronized block on the same Object.

Answer (score 1):

Synchronization in Java is cooperative, not mandatory.  What I mean is, you want synchronization to protect your *data*, but the language only lets you synchronize the blocks of code that manipulate your data.  It's your responsibility to make sure that all of the code that can touch your data is synchronized.

(That's what some of the other answers mean when they say, "synchronization is code-level, not object-level.)

In your example, you wrote a synchronized block of code that manipulates your list.  That will prevent two or more threads from entering *that* block of code at the same time, but it will not generally prevent other threads from concurrently manipulating the list from within other blocks of code even if one thread is in the synchronized block.

Also note:  The monitor object (the Object on which you synchronized) need not be part of the data that you are trying to protect.  You might for example, have two Lists; and you might want to guarantee a certain relationship between the two lists (e.g., both must be the same length).  In that case, which List do you synchronized on?  The answer may be neither.  E.g.,

```
private Object lock = new Object();
private List<Foo> fooList = ...;
private List<Bar> barList = ...;

... doSomethingFascinating(...) {
    synchronized(lock) {
        //Use your shameful imagination here.
    }
}
```